# Parse Server S3 Adapter Deprecated

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, parse-server

The Parse S3 Adapter's requirement of `S3_ACCESS_KEY` and `S3_SECRET_KEY` is now deprecated. It says to use the environment variables: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. We are have setup an AWS user with an Access Key ID and we have our secret key as well. We have updated to the latest version of the adapter and removed our old `S3_X_Key` variables. Unfortunately, as soon as we do this we are unable to access, upload or change files on our S3 bucket. The user does have access to our buckets properties and if we change it back to use the explicit `S3_ACCESS_KEY` and secret everything works.

We are hosting on Heroku and haven't had any issues until now.

What else needs to be done to set this up?

This deprecation notice is very vague on how to fix this. 
(link to notice: https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-server-s3-adapter#deprecation-notice----aws-credentials)

Comment: I'm having trouble with this too. I removed the `S3Adapter` instance and tried to only use environment variables, but just noticed that all my files are now being saved directly to the db. I'll let you know if I get it figured out.

Comment: Thanks, this is the hard part of open source... questionable documentation and weird issues! :) Will let you know if I figure it out as well.

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: Not yet, I'm just about to start working on it again so if you found anything please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arjav Dave's answer below is best if you are using AWS or a hosting solution where you can login to the server and run the AWS Configure command on the server. Or if you are running everything locally.

However, I was asking about Heroku and this goes for any server environment where you can set ENV variables.

Really it comes down to just a few steps. If you have a previous version setup you are going to switch your file adapter to just read: 
`filesAdapter: 'parse-server-s3-adapter',`
(or whatever your npm installed package is called some are using the `@parse/...` one)

Take out the `require` statement and don't create any instance variables of `S3Adapter` or anything like that in your index.js.

Then in Heroku.com create config vars or with the CLI: `heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=abc` and `heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=abc`

Now run and test your uploading. All should be good.

The new adapter uses the environment variables for access and you just have to tell it what file adapter is installed in the index.js file. It will handle the rest. If this isn't working it'll be worth testing the IAM profile setup and making sure it's all working before coming back to this part. See below:

Still not working? Try running this example (edit sample.js to be your bucket when testing):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html

**Completely lost and no idea where to start?**

**1 Get Your AWS Credentials:** 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-your-credentials.html

**2 Setup  Your Bucket**
https://transloadit.com/docs/faq/how-to-set-up-an-amazon-s3-bucket/ 
(follow the part on IAM users as well)

**3 Follow IAM Best Practices**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html

Then go back to the top of this posting.

Hope that helps anyone else that was confused by this.

Comment: This will work as long as you don't need to pass options to the adapter. If you do you should use for example: `filesAdapter: {module: '@parse/s3-files-adapter', options: {bucketPrefix: 'myBucketPrefix'}}`

Comment: That said, you may not need to pass options as they should all be available via environment variables, e.g. bucketPrefix is set from S3_BUCKET_PREFIX

Comment: Now that it's been a little while of using it this way... this is actually much better. We can switch from development to production and this is one less thing we have to change on the code level. We just setup our ENV variables and it's working great out of the box.

Comment: Answers like this is what makes Stack Overflow so special

Answer (score 4):

I did the following steps and it's working now:

1. Installed Amazon's CLI
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html
2. Configured CLI by creating a user and then creating key id and secret
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html
3. Set the S3_BUCKET env variable

   export S3_BUCKET=
4. Installed files adapter using command

   ```
   npm install --save @parse/s3-files-adapter
   ```
5. In my parse-server's index.js added the files adapter

   ```
   var S3Adapter = require('@parse/s3-files-adapter');
   var s3Adapter = new S3Adapter();

   var api = new ParseServer({
       appId: 'my_app',
       masterKey: 'master_key',
       filesAdapter: s3Adapter
   })
   ```

Comment: I set it up as above but I'm getting the following error: "missing credentials in config". Have you seen anything like that?

Comment: No haven't got any such error message. Make sure your aws credentials are setup correctly. The aws credentials file is stored at ~/.aws/credentials. Can you attach your logs.

Comment: Can you explain what you did in step 3 a little more? Did you just declare the S3_BUCKET and where?

Comment: I think I understand what you did now. This is if you are logged into the server and adding the export to the .env's right? If you are on Heroku or something similar you will need to do something else right?

Comment: @DevKyle I'm seeing the same thing. Did you ever get this figured out? I think that the proposed solution only works for AWS hosts or where you can log into the server. Not for Heroku.

Comment: @DavidNelson Yes, I was able to figure this out for Heroku. If you ask this as a separate question specifically for Heroku, I'll answer it on that thread step by step so that other ppl can refer to it. I'll make a pull request on github as well.

Comment: @DavidNelson Sorry for the late reply. Yes you are correct, in AWS I have set up the environment variables. I haven't got much experience with Heroku, but am sure there must be a way to do so.

Comment: Just found this for Heroku for setting config/environment variables: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-a-parse-server-to-heroku#configuring-your-parse-server-with-config-vars

Comment: Thanks, and just for reference this is the same as setting them within the dashboard but more convenient if you don't want to login to Heroku.